# How to wrap line by command line option

Tags: vim

In most case, I don't want the vim to wrap line, is there command line options could I set to let vim launch with wrap line?

I've tested the following command, but failed

```
vim --cmd "set wrap" -do origin.txt new.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

see `vim -h` there is a `-c` flag to execute a command *after* the initialization so `vim -c "set wrap"` should do it

Answer (score 2):

if you used `--cmd`, your command will be executed before the vimrc settings. That is, the settings could be overwritten by vimrc.

Try `-c`, this will be executed after the file was read.